# DLL function gets wrong value from parameter

Tags: c++, dll

I have a problem with a dll function call.
The function call take a struct as parameter and the struct contains a double among other data types.
After call to the function the value of the double in the struct the function gets is totally different from what it was before passing to the function, something like -2.343443e4535.

here's a snippet of the call, all the dll function does for now is just print the value of the double in the struct (second parameter).

```
TRD_ADD myFunc= (ADD) GetProcAddress(hinstLib,"MyFunc");
Mystruct * trd = new Mystruct(1,11.1,0,0,0,0,134000);
(myFunc) (trd);
```

Here's the struct and function

```
#pragma pack(1)
struct MyStruct
 {
   int               orderNum;                     
   int               id;                   
   char              symbol[12];                 
   int               cmd;     
   char              comment[32];               
   int               internal_id;                
   int               activation;                 
   int               count;                      
   double            rate;               
   time_t            timestamp;                  
   int               reserved[4];  
   double            price;

    Mystruct(_orderNum,_rate,_timestamp,_activation,_cmd,_id,_price):orderNum(_orderNum),rate(_rate),timestamp(_timestamp),activation(_activation),cmd(_cmd),id(_id),price(_price){}
};
#pragma (pop) 
void APIENTRY MyFunc(MyStruct *myStruct)
{
   std::cout << myStruct->rate;
};
```

I forgot to include those #pragma's . The code is from a restricted API that's why I cannot publish the actual code but this exactly the same structure.

Thanks

Comment: May we see your structure implementation and the one that the dll use.
It can be a data padding disorder.

Comment: Can you show us the definition of Mystruct and the code for MyFunc.  There's no way anyone can help you debug code they can't see.

Comment: Thats all the function does for now.

Comment: Can you provide ADD and TRD_ADD?  Could be a calling convention mismatch.

Comment: If the definition of `MyStruct` differs between the compilation of the main routine and the compilation of the dll, you could get this issue.

Comment: You may check if sizeof(MyStruct) is the same when called from the dll and from the calling module. You may also try to put the 'rate' at the very beginning of the struct, just to see if it changes anything. It should confirm what others people are already suspecting.

Comment: You can also force the struct's alignment using `#pragma` statements so it is not affected by external alignment settings.

Comment: Same compiler for dll and exe?

Comment: "The code is from a restricted API that's why I cannot publish the actual code but this exactly the same structure." That's fine, but in that case your question has been answered has it not? We obviously can't tell you the specifics of how your structs are mismatched if you only show us one side of the interface. Are expecting more help with this?

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig Yes, Same compiler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only plausible explanation for what you report is that the DLL has a different definition of the struct. And so when the calling code writes to members of the struct, it writes to different offsets from the offsets used in the DLL.

In the statement above, I mean also to cover the possibility that the layout of the struct is different in the DLL from that in the calling code. As it happens, for 32 bit targets, the packed and aligned layouts of your struct are the same. For 64 bit targets, packed and aligned differ. .

It's hard to say what the mismatch is from the code that you have posted. Unfortunately you seem to be a little shy. If you could only publish the entire code, for both the DLL and the code that consumes the DLL, it would be easy to tell you what the mismatch is. So, as it stands I'm afraid you'll have to work out the rest of the details, unless you can manage to publish complete code.

Comment: Something else to watch out for. The definition of the struct may match, but the padding may not.

Comment: @RemyLebeau To me the alignment should be considered as part of the definition of the struct. For a 32 bit target, packed and aligned layouts are the same, for this struct, as it happens.

Comment: The DLL was built with a Preproccessor directive of _USE_32BIT_TIME_T while the console app wasn't and the default was 64 BIT, this made the structs to misalign. Adding that directive to the Console app solve the issue.
I'm indeed grateful David

Comment: @Kraz Thanks for the accept and I'm pleased you got to the bottom of this puzzle.